# Permissions dialog does not show up anymore

Tags: javascript, facebook

When a user logs into my website, I want to post a message to the user's wall. Therefore I use this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="permission()">post on wall</a>

function permission() {
    FB.login(wallPost, {perms: 'publish_stream'})
}

function wallPost() {
    var wall = { message: 'testing wallpost'};
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wall, function (response) {
        if (!response) {
            alert("noresponse");
        } else if (response.error) {
            alert("response error");
        } else {
             alert('Post succesfull!" (post id: ' + response.id + ")");
        }
    });
}
```

So when a user clicks the link, the user gets a pop-up for the `publish_stream` permission. And when the users allows it, the post is succesful. The first three times I tested this, it worked fine, but now, for some reason, this code does not work anymore (I get the alert "response error")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'scope' instead of 'perms' in the login button. This changed on October 1st 2011.

Comment: thank you, that works fine, but now when i press the button for the second time, i get the alert "response error" again? any ideas?

Comment: isn't it possible that Facebook has secured wallposting from external pages, so you can't spam somebody's wall?